# FLUTTER Json local file reading and detail page

Tags: json, flutter, local, ontap

Hello everybody i'm new to flutter so i'm making this project and i get an issue. i want to have a detail page of the items listed with a json local file. but i get errors i don't know where  is my mistake. so i hope find the solution
here  is my code :

```
    import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MaladieDetails {
  final String titreCh;
  final String numCh;
  final String titreCat;
  final String codeM;
  final String titreM;
  final String classeM;

  MaladieDetails(
      {required this.titreCh,
      required this.numCh,
      required this.titreCat,
      required this.codeM,
      required this.titreM,
      required this.classeM});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Kindacode.com',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // This holds a list of fiction maladies
  // You can use data fetched from a database or a server as well
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _maladies = [
{
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00",
      "titre_m": "Choléra",
      "classe_m": "Choléra"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00.0",
      "titre_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae",
      "classe_m": "Choléra",
      "explication_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00.1",
      "titre_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar El Tor",
      "classe_m": "Choléra",
      "explication_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar El Tor"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00.9",
      "titre_m": "Choléra, sans précision",
      "classe_m": "Choléra",
      "explication_m": "Choléra, sans précision"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01",
      "titre_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.0",
      "titre_m": "Fièvre typhoïde",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Fièvre typhoïde"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.1",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde A",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde A"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.2",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde B",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde B"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.3",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde C",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde C"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.4",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde, sans précision",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde, sans précision"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A02",
      "titre_m": "Autres infections à Salmonella",
      "classe_m": "Autres infections à Salmonella"
    },
];

  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _trouverMaladies = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all maladies are shown
    _trouverMaladies = _maladies;
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all maladies
      results = _maladies;
    } else {
      results = _maladies
          .where((maladie) => maladie["titre_m"]
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _trouverMaladies = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Kindacode.com'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Cherchez ...', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _trouverMaladies.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _trouverMaladies.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        elevation: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            _trouverMaladies[index]["code_m"].toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_trouverMaladies[index]['titre_m']),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              _trouverMaladies[index]["titre_cat"].toString()),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => DetailScreen(
                                    maladieDetails: _trouverMaladies[index]
                                        ['titre_m']),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'No results found',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // In the constructor, require a maladieDetails.
  const DetailScreen({super.key, required this.maladieDetails});

  // Declare a field that holds the maladieDetails.
  final MaladieDetails maladieDetails;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the maladieDetails to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(maladieDetails.titreM),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(maladieDetails.codeM),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the errors shows after i choose an item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing is the deserialization from the JSON to the `MaladieDetails` entity object. Generally, it's a function called `fromJson` that is responsible to deserialize the JSON into the entity properties.

I've implemented the `MaladieDetails.fronJson` and changed some other places to make it work. Take a look:

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MaladieDetails {
  final String titreCh;
  final String numCh;
  final String titreCat;
  final String codeM;
  final String titreM;
  final String classeM;

  MaladieDetails(
      {required this.titreCh,
      required this.numCh,
      required this.titreCat,
      required this.codeM,
      required this.titreM,
      required this.classeM});

  MaladieDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : titreCh = json['titre_ch'],
        numCh = json['num_ch'],
        titreCat = json['titre_cat'],
        codeM = json['code_m'],
        titreM = json['titre_m'],
        classeM = json['classe_m'];
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Kindacode.com',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // This holds a list of fiction maladies
  // You can use data fetched from a database or a server as well
  final _maladies = [
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00",
      "titre_m": "Choléra",
      "classe_m": "Choléra"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00.0",
      "titre_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae",
      "classe_m": "Choléra",
      "explication_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00.1",
      "titre_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar El Tor",
      "classe_m": "Choléra",
      "explication_m": "A Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar El Tor"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A00.9",
      "titre_m": "Choléra, sans précision",
      "classe_m": "Choléra",
      "explication_m": "Choléra, sans précision"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01",
      "titre_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.0",
      "titre_m": "Fièvre typhoïde",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Fièvre typhoïde"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.1",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde A",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde A"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.2",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde B",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde B"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.3",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde C",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde C"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A01.4",
      "titre_m": "Paratyphoïde, sans précision",
      "classe_m": "Fièvres typhoïde et paratyphoïde",
      "explication_m": "Paratyphoïde, sans précision"
    },
    {
      "titre_ch": "Certaines maladies infectieuses et parasitaires",
      "num_ch": "1",
      "titre_cat": "Maladies intestinales infectieuses",
      "code_m": "A02",
      "titre_m": "Autres infections à Salmonella",
      "classe_m": "Autres infections à Salmonella"
    },
  ].map((e) => MaladieDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();

  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<MaladieDetails> _trouverMaladies = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all maladies are shown
    _trouverMaladies = [..._maladies];
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<MaladieDetails> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all maladies
      results = [..._maladies];
    } else {
      results = _maladies
          .where((maladie) => maladie.titreM
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _trouverMaladies = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Kindacode.com'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Cherchez ...', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _trouverMaladies.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _trouverMaladies.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        elevation: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            _trouverMaladies[index].codeM,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_trouverMaladies[index].titreM),
                          subtitle: Text(_trouverMaladies[index].titreCat),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => DetailScreen(
                                    maladieDetails: _trouverMaladies[index]),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'No results found',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // In the constructor, require a maladieDetails.
  const DetailScreen({super.key, required this.maladieDetails});

  // Declare a field that holds the maladieDetails.
  final MaladieDetails maladieDetails;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the maladieDetails to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(maladieDetails.titreM),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(maladieDetails.codeM),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```